# "Calendar Overlay Settings page"? Where is it?

Tags: calendar, sharepoint-calendar

I'm trying to figure out how to add an existing Exchange group calendar to a team sharepoint site.  I keep coming across the exact same instructions that start with "Click the calendar tab" then "Calendar Overlays".

I don't even see a calendar "tab" let alone anything to do with overlays.

When I click the help icon, it says "Sharepoint Services 3.0" if that helps determine what version my company uses...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows SharePoint Services (WSS) 3.0 is pre SharePoint 2010 where the ribbon was introduced (where you would find the tabbed interfaced etc.). In other words, unfortunately you are following instructions for the wrong version.

Comment: Gah, I was hoping I was using a NEWER version... wishful thinking.

Comment: No problem. You're using the free version released in 2007. See SharePoint version history [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SharePoint#versions) for details.

Comment: Yeah, multi-billion dollar health system or not, I'm not surprised... :(